# select specific json value in Postgres SQL based on a condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a json string in col1 :

```
col1                   col2

{min: x, max:y}        val1
```

I want to select x (or y) from col1 based on col2,

select col1["min"] where col2 > 10
is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using `CASE` clause

```
select 
 case
  when col2>10 then col1::json->>'min'
  else
   col1::json->>'max'
 end as  val
from ...
```